# Mestre-detalhe em MVC Spring

Tags: java, spring, bootstrap, thymeleaf

Prezados tenho uma tela de usuário, a mesma esta com todas as funções de crud, meu próximo passo é implementar a inclusão de Papeis( rules ), como venho de um ambiente desktop relacionamentos muito para muito usamos uma grade, aqui em html seria uma tabela, procurei informações de telas mestre detalhe para exemplo mais para minha surpresa não encontrei, nem para o meu caso que é a tela de usuário nem para telas mais comuns como de pedidos, orçamento, notas.

Sei que não é só desenhar a tabela no html tem o lado do controller mais devido a não ter achado material sobre o assunto para mestre detalhe minha pergunta é sera que estou certo em buscar um desinger mestre detalhe tudo na mesma tela? é realmente desta forma que é feito isto hoje com estas tecnologias?

Meu projeto esta fazendo uso do Spring, para o engine Html estou usando o Thymeleaf e o bootstrap para o css